# Can I hide hosts with "No matching services" in Nagios Groups?

Tags: nagios

In the Nagios web interface, I want to offer a user access to particular services on one particular host: "you can monitor the status of http and your wordpress installation".

It works well in the Hosts and Services views.

We also have Host Groups (like "our servers") and Service Groups (like "wordpress"), each also containing items that the user has no access to.

- In Nagios 3.2.3 (Ubuntu 12.04), a user will only see such a host group or service group if they have permission to all the hosts/services in that group. So they see neither "our webservers" nor "wordpress".
- In Nagios 3.4.1 (Ubuntu 12.10), a user will see a group if they have access to at least one item in that group. **But...** now they see all hosts/services in that group, and all but their own host reporting "No matching services".

I'd like to show those groups, but within each group only the hosts and services they actually have access to.

I haven't found a way to hide the other hosts with "No matching services" from the group lists. Is that possible at all through configuration?